# PHP ffmpeg flv stream Passthru

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to transcode a mpeg2 stream into a x264 flv stream, and pass it through php to a flash player. My ffmpeg command works fine from the command line, but when I wrap it in php's `passthru()` function php does not output anything (from a browser or from the flash player I am using).

my code is:

```
header('Content-type: video/x-flv');
passthru('ffmpeg -y -i http://192.168.0.199:5004/auto/v10 -threads 0 -f flv -vf yadif,scale="iw/2*sar:ih/2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset:v ultrafast -b:v 1000k -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 32k -ar 11025 -strict -2 /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null');`
```

This works when I run the php file from the command line using `php -f test.php` or when I run just the `ffmpeg` command from the command line. In the browser the header is sent but nothing else, I am assuming this is also what the flash player is seeing too.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Transcoding each request is a HORRIBLE thing to do. You should transcode on upload, and cache the results. That's what YouTube does.

Comment: I would do that but I am trying to transcode a live tv stream from my network tv tuner.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with PHP? Just use the Adobe Flash Media Encoder, (or maybe some other software like ManyCam to play the video file) and then stream it out either to a streaming server, or make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out what was going wrong here, ffmpeg was not in the path of the www-data user, so I included the path to ffmpeg in my command and now it works! I also like the suggestion to use ffserver, instead of using php to do this, I am now working on implementing this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to serve the item directly, it would be best to use ffmpeg server. Here is a link to a great description on how to do it:
http://www.area536.com/projects/streaming-video/
Hope that works,
~techdude