# Return a file while it's being processed by FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to modify an audio file and send the result back using FFMPEG and PHP, I therefore have this code:

```php
header("Content-Type: audio/wav");
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i \"" . __DIR__ . "/../data/" . $_GET['file'] . "\" -f wav pipe:1");
```

It works well however it wait for the whole file to be processed before returning it and I would like to be able to play it bit by bit
I saw that you can use flush and ob_flush however I'm not sure how I can use it in my case, since I'm just redirecting shell_exec output
I also heard you can use -flush_packets in FFMPEG but it doesn't seem to do much in my base

So my question is, is there a way to process a file using FFMPEG and return what is being processed bit by bit?

Comment: There's a couple of posts here that you could try, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586988/231316, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52569823/231316, however they also might only be about the progress, not the data